# How to deserialize name-value collection pairs from a JSON string into an object?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, json.net

I am trying to deserialize a JSON string into a strongly typed `Payment` class as defined below. The JSON contains some name-value pairs in the `items` collection. How can I deserialize these into the `ID` and `PersonName` properties on my class?

My JSON:

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "amount": 200.0,
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "ID",
      "value": "123456"
    },
    {
      "name": "PersonName",
      "value": "test"
    }
  ]
}
```

My class:

```
public class Payment
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Amount { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string PersonName { get; set; }
}
```

Here is how I am trying to deserialize it:

```
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Payment>(message);
```

Comment: You will need to use a custom `JsonConverter` that knows how to interpret the items collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use a custom [`JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) to do what you want.  Below is a generic one which should do the job.  The converter works by first loading the JSON into a [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm), then converterting the items array into regular properties on the `JObject`, and finally populating the target class from the `JObject`.

```
public class ClassWithItemsConverter<T> : JsonConverter where T : class, new()
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(T);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);
        JProperty items = jo.Property("items");
        if (items != null && items.Value.Type == JTokenType.Array)
        {
            foreach (JObject item in items.Value.Children<JObject>())
            {
                jo.Add((string)item["name"], item["value"]);
            }
            items.Remove();
        }
        T result = new T();
        serializer.Populate(jo.CreateReader(), result);
        return result;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }   
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You can use the converter by adding a `[JsonConverter]` attribute to your target class like this:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(ClassWithItemsConverter<Payment>))]
public class Payment
{
    ...
}
```

Here is a working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/IuHT3O